# cntlm on linux server

Tags: security, proxy

I have a local linux server PC, for a small subnetwork cluster. The server accesses internet using CNTLM (since I am behind a corporate NTLM proxy). This poses the following security problem.

CNTLM listens through a specific port, and redirects all traffic coming in this port to the corporate proxy, using some authentication details. The problem is that *anyone* with access to the cluster can send traffic through this port, which then automatically gets redirected and authenticated to the corporate proxy.

I want to restrict this access to only some specific users on the cluster. What can I do? Assume that the NTLM is given as it is by God, I cannot configure that. All I can do is from the local linux server.

Is it possible to make CNTLM block requests from unauthorized users? Or is it possible to block access to a port number for certain users (rather, I want to allow only specific users to use the port, all other users should be blocked by default)? Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. It might not be the best solution but its working now. I'd appreciate to hear downsides or possible security loopholes.

I created a blocking rule using `iptables` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119726/iptables-rule-to-allow-only-one-port-and-block-others). Then only a specific admin user can use the port that `cntlm` is listening.